# Amazon Postgres RDS pg_stat_statements not loaded

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I configured my RDS Postgres 9.6.1 instance so, that the pg_stat_activity is loaded via 'shared_preload_libraries' parameter

```
shared_preload_libraries=pg_stat_statements,pg_hint_plan
```

The I rebooted my instance and then check if the pg_stat_statements can be loaded. But I get the error:

```
[55000] ERROR: pg_stat_statements must be loaded via shared_preload_libraries
```

The command

```
SHOW shared_preload_libraries;
```

does not show the pg_stat_statements library.

And therefore the error above still remains.

Does somebody else has got the same issue?

Comment: RDS supports `pg_stat_statements`. `shared_preload_libraries=pg_stat_statements,pg_hint_plan` change to `shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements,pg_hint_plan'` and restart again please

Answer (score 5):

Ran into the same problem today.

Turns out I simply had to **reboot the database** (via CLI or web interface).

As mentioned on the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html):

> When you change a static parameter and save the DB parameter group, **the parameter change takes effect after you manually reboot the DB instance**.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

I tried myself. Added to Parameters->shared_preload_libraries values:`pg_stat_statements,pg_hint_plan`. Clicked "save changes", agreed on "Apply Immediately". Indeed no effect. When I check *DB Parameter Group* - it shows modified group, but `pg_stat_statements` unusable. So I think bad on JS and try `aws cli`:

```
aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier p5
```

it reveals that group was not indeed changed!:

```
"OptionGroupMemberships": [
    {
      "Status": "in-sync",
      "OptionGroupName": "default:postgres-9-5"
    }
  ],
```

So I did:

```
aws rds modify-db-instance --db-parameter-group-name with-contrib --apply-immediately --db-instance-identifier p5
aws rds reboot-db-instance --db-instance-identifier p5
aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier p5
```

And It was changed. So I try to:

```
mon=> create extension pg_stat_statements ;
CREATE EXTENSION
mon=> select count(*) from pg_stat_statements;
 count
-------
    26
(1 row)
```

Voila. Not sure if it was Chrome (Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)) feature or JS failure, or me not getting intuitive clicking steps, but I failed to apply changes as well. Please try with `aws cli` to see if you success there.

**PREVIOUS**
[String requires quotes I think.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html):

> **String:** In general, enclose the value in single quotes, doubling any
>   single quotes within the value. Quotes can usually be omitted if the
>   value is a simple number or identifier, however.

So maybe setting shared_preload_libraries this way will help:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements,pg_hint_plan'
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html:

> shared_preload_libraries **(string)**
>
> This variable specifies one or more shared libraries to be preloaded
>   at server start. This parameter can only be set at server start. If a
>   specified library is not found, the server will fail to start.

Comment: In the AWS config screen the  "shared_preload_libraries" key must be specified without single quotes.

Comment: ah, yes - theres no postgres.conf, theres some parameter group page or smth..., what's in logs after you restart cluster?..

Comment: nothing really. it does not show any error. When trying to do select * from pg_stat_statements it says : 'ERROR:  pg_stat_statements must be loaded via shared_preload_libraries'

Comment: @DetlefBrendle try `aws rds modify-db-instance --db-parameter-group-name with-contrib --apply-immediately --db-instance-identifier iname
aws rds reboot-db-instance --db-instance-identifier iname` if it helps. updated the answer